# How to give default value to a column in a table if there's no data in it?

Tags: mysql, sql

For eg: 
We have a table `Person` with columns `Name, Age`.

If the table `Person` is empty, I want to have default value as `"no person"` in `Name` column and `0` in `age` column.

How do we do that?

I tried `IFNULL` but it doesn't give any default value. It shows the table as empty only.

Comment: Do you really mean if the entire table is empty, or just the column in a specific row?

Comment: I am trying to select few columns from a table with conditions. If the results has no value, then I have to provide a default saying no name, 0 for age.

Answer (score 1):

Use a union with a query that checks the number of rows in the table:

```
SELECT name, age
FROM Persons
UNION ALL
SELECT 'no person', 0
FROM DUAL
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Persons) = 0
```

`DUAL` is a dummy table name that can be used in queries that don't need to refer to a real table.

Comment: Shouldn't the second IF condition in select have IF(age=' ') ?

Comment: I assume `age` is an integer, not a string.

Comment: I tested it. It doesn't work. Could you suggest some other way?

Comment: I just added a link to a sqlfiddle demo, it works for me.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you want. Show sample table contents and the desired result.

Comment: In the demo which you have provided. It is a particular column which doesn't have any value, and for that you are displaying no person. In my case, the table doesn't have any data. So It should say that no person and age should be 0

Answer (score 0):

use `COALESCE`

```
select case when name<>''
then COALESCE (name,'No name') else 'No name' end,
 COALESCE (age,0) from Person
```

Comment: `COALESCE` is the same as `IFNULL` (except `IFNULL` only allows 2 arguments), so why would this work better?

Comment: @Zaynul It doesn't work. Could you suggest some other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that kind of output from the database? I think you should do that from the language you use to process the data the Query provides you. I think the suggested solutions are wrong cause they just give an empty set if the table is empty

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do this in the database, you'd do it in the front end.

If you absolutely insist that the DB should provide this data, then one possible query would look like this:

```
SELECT Name, Age FROM Person
UNION ALL
SELECT 'No person', 0 FROM dual a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Person)
```

All these guys suggesting COALESCE or IFNULL seem to have overlooked the fact that there aren't any rows to at all. In the query above, the bottom query (everything after the UNION ALL) is a query that results in one row if Person has no records in it

Comment: One more doubt, suppose person table has few more columns and I have applied some condition on it and getting no values while extracting the result. In that how would I get the default values?